# How to execute a cmd command in browser with js

Tags: javascript

As the title,not only in IE.
If js can not do this,is there other way to do this?
It's best to show a demo code.

Comment: If you are using this locally, then just create a simple local server (using for example [**nodeJs**](https://nodejs.org/en/)) that execute the commands send from the page (browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with Javascript.  Browsers are deliberately isolated from the host machine to prevent malicious behaviour.  So the amount of access to local resources is extremely limited (eg. uploading a file) and can only be initiated by the user.

In the past, you could have used ActiveX controls or Java applets to perform these types of actions, but Oracle has discontinued its browser plugin for applets and ActiveX controls do not run on all browsers.

Comment: It's helpful,thanks!